# Multiprocessing Pool Threads Parent Function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have a few scripts I am running from one Python file but one of the scripts contains some multiprocessing code and it appears to be parallelizing the parent function.

In the below script, the results of `func_1` and `func_2` are printed multiple times as if they were threaded but only the result of `func_3`, where the multiprocessing occurs, should print multiple times.

```
run_main():
   func_1()
   func_2()
   func_3() #Contains multiprocessing
```

Output:

```
func_1_output
func_2_output
func_3_output
func_1_output
func_2_output
.
.
.
```

`func_3()` implementatin of multiprocessing:

```
pool = Pool(process=CONST_NUM)
input_list = [a,b,c,d]
output = pool.map(helper_func, input_list)
```

Comment: what is `helper_func`?

Comment: What appears to be parallelizing the parent function?

Comment: @OlvinRoght it opens a web browser and performs some web scrapping on a link contained in input_list

Comment: @martineau the other functions in run_main are run multiple times where they should be run just once.

Comment: Could you list how run_main() is called?

Comment: It would be very unusual for a called "child" function to be parallelizing the "parent" function that called it — so I think that analysis/explanation in wrong.

Comment: `multiprocessing` requires that there be no top-level code outside of a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.  This sounds like the kind of problem you get if you violate that requirement.

Comment: @jasonharper would the same issue come up with multithreading?

Comment: No, the `threading` module has no such restrictions.